# Non-latin letters in test script result in "No translation for key. Assuming unicode input..."

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

When I execute on Windows7+Ruby1.9.2+watir-webdriver this test script:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
ie = Watir::Browser.new :ie
ie.goto "www.tilde.eu"
ie.select_list(:name => "tr-direction").select "Latvian-English"
ie.select_list(:name => "tr-direction").selected? "Latvian-English"
ie.text_field(:class => "tr-area").set "skolas dārzā aug divas priedes"
ie.element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input").click
Watir::Wait.until { ie.text.include? "About Tilde Machine Translation" }
puts ie.div(:class => "translate_text_result").text
```

Script executes fine as it is in Firefox, but IE9 crashes when trying to set "ā" letter in text field and CMD shows following:

```
No translation for key. Assuming unicode input: 257
Timeout awaiting keypress: 82
Key up failed: 1400
Key down failed: 1400
Timeout awaiting keypress: 90
Key up failed: 1400
No translation for key. Assuming unicode input: 257
Key down failed: 1400
```

Script executes completely in Chrome, but still some warning in CMD are shown:

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=52409
version=14.0.836.0
[0825/095000:WARNING:webdriver_key_converter.cc(271)] No translation for key code. Code point: 257
[0825/095000:WARNING:webdriver_key_converter.cc(271)] No translation for key code. Code point: 257
```

Do I need to specify anything else apart from `# encoding: utf-8` for it to work correctly in IE and Chrome?

I suggest to excecute above script on your computer to determine if this is common issue or just something in my configuration.

Comment: Noone has ever faced such problem? If so, I'm guessing if this could somehow be related to keyboard layout? I am using custom one not windows standard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the IE driver, which you can follow [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1613). The warnings in Chrome are harmless, though they probably shouldn't be printed by default.

Comment: Sadly there's no solution or hacks to get through with this. Preferably without redesigning test scripts specifically for IE.

Comment: Could you switch to the Watir IE driver for this testing?

Comment: It really works if I use watir instead of watir-webdriver for IE. Couldn`t even imagine that watir and watir-webdriver can differ in such way. Thank`s for advise.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that issue is actual only if non-windows keyboard layout is set.
If any of standard windows layouts is set e.g. "Latvian(QWERTY)" on script execution machine, IE doesn't crash anymore just outputs warnings similar to Chrome.

Temporary hack until IE driver bug is fixed could be to set standard windows keyboard layout before execution of test suite and to revert to previous one after execution.

[How to get the keyboard layout on windows with ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857320/how-to-get-the-keyboard-layout-on-windows-with-ruby) - for inspiration.